# CSS Columns on UL vs DIV

Tags: html, css

Why is the output for

```
<div class="tcol">
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

different from

```
<div>
  <ul class="tcol">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

with this CSS?

```
.tcol
{
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

I don't understand why an empty line is rendered.

How can I either remove the empty line in the first list or get the bullet points in the second one?

[Live demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jzchris/3LyjL/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements have default styles, browsers apply those default styles if you don't specifically define them.

It's a good practice to use a CSS reset on your projects and then define the styles the way you need them.

Here is a good source for a start:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

For example in your case FireFox renders a `16px` top and bottom margin for the `UL` element (default box model).

Comment: I disagree. I don't think it is good practice to use CSS resets. I recommend reading [one good article](http://sixrevisions.com/css/should-you-reset-your-css/) against CSS reset but also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet which presents sides of the discussion.

Comment: @andyb while I respect your opinion, most of the mentioned "downwards" of using a CSS reset are said to be "forgetting to place a proper replacement for the reset styles" (For presentation, for keyboards users) and also an increased size of styles. This can be overcome by well written styles.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your point correctly as I sounds like you are also not recommending CSS resets. I agree well written styles often negate the need to have a CSS reset but sometimes they are useful, for example Twitter Bootstrap's reset.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin:0` to ul

```
.tcol
{
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
ul{
    margin:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3LyjL/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Due to the browser splitting the `<li>` into columns, the `list-style-type` has been pushed out of the normal view. You can correct this by adding `list-style-position: inside;` property to your *tcol* class.

There is also a very visible difference between the two layouts, not counting the missing list-style-type. Using the *Elements* panel in Chrome and hovering each `<ul>` and `<li>` you can see how the browser is laying out the column content.

The second version of your markup seems to be more "correct", with the container correctly encompassing the list-items.