# Small unwanted space on top and bottom of page

Tags: css, html

I have a to most probably simple problem.
My page has a background color and contains a container, then a contentcontainer to put the page in the middle. Now this content container has a different background color, but a small space where we see the original page background color is visible at the top and bottom.

The CSS file is like this:

```
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #E0EBED;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#contentcontainer {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The body looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="contentcontainer">
        <p>Some content</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

What do I have to to to make this small space disappear.
I have already tried to add 0 top padding to the container div and body.

After a few answers I have discovered that margin: 0; the body css takes out the space at the top. I still have the same kind of space at the bottom though.

To show people what I mean:
[image: bottom screenshot]

**NOW THIS IS THE FIX:**

CSS:

```
body,td,th {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #E0EBED;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
}

#contentcontainer {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I added **margin: 0;** to body and **height: 100%;** to content container. If you have the same problem do not forget to add the **margin: 0;** to the body as it will not work without that.

Thanks to all that answered this question and helped me solve this!

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231257/css-columns-on-ul-vs-div/16231488#16231488

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, you can post the solution not in the question, but as an answer, that's totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Space at the top is gone, but still exists at the bottom :(

Comment: What do you mean at the bottom? Could you elaborate just a bit?

Comment: The bottom of the page. So the entire middle is white now, but stops and leaves about one line at the bottom showing the body background again.

Comment: I know this is probably not semantic... but you could try this... ' :root, body { background: #E0EBED ; }'

Comment: Doesn't work. This is what I mean: http://picpaste.com/screenshot_bottom-hWhfZrdk.jpg

Comment: Oh! Make the height 100% content container.   '#contentcontainer { height: 100%; }' I just tried it on fiddle.

Comment: Works! Strange though as I tried it before but without adding margin: 0; to the body. With the margin: 0; and making the height of the #contentcontainer 100% it works!

Answer (score 0):

body has padding by default. Make it 0px by -

```
body{padding:0px;}
```

Comment: That unfortunately has no effect.